# How to keep object of subclass in another class in cpp? Base class undefined error

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm coding simple shop program in cpp. I have 3 classes: Shop, Client, Bucket. Shop is parent class for Bucket. Shop has vector of clients and every client has his own bucket.
I've got problem with #include's. I have to include Client.h in Shop.h so the Shop could see the vector of clients, but it seems I also have to include Bucket.h in Clinet.h for similar reason.
This generates a problem: Bucket is being included before Shop so I get 'Base Class Undefined' error.
How can I make this work?

Shop.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "functions.h"
#include "Client.h"

class Shop {

protected:
    std::vector<int> quantities;
    std::vector<std::string> products;
    std::vector<float> prices;
private:
    std::vector<Client*> clients;
    int loggedClient;
public:
    Shop();
    ~Shop();
    int readProducts();
    int loadClientsBase();
    int checkLoginData(std::string log, std::string pass, int *logged);
    int checkIfSameLogin(std::string log);
    int addClient();
    void login();
    void logout();
    int sell();
    virtual void display();
    void displayLoggedClient();
    int saveHistory();
};
```

Client.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Bucket.h"


class Client
{
private:
    float money=0.0;
    Bucket bucket;
    std::string login;
    std::string password;
    std::string description;
public:
    Client();
    ~Client();
    void addLoginData(std::string log, std::string pass, std::string desc, float mon);
    std::string getLogin() { return login; };
    std::string getPassword() { return password; };
    std::string getDescription() { return description; };
    float getMoney() { return money; };
    void addLogin(std::string log);
    void addPassword(std::string pass);
    void addDescription(std::string desc);
    void addMoney(float m);
    void addToBucket(std::string prod, int quant, float price);
    void displayBucket();
    Bucket getBucket() { return bucket; };

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Client& client);
};
```

Bucket.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string> 
#include "Shop.h"


class Bucket : public Shop
{
public:
    Bucket();
    ~Bucket();
    void addProduct(std::string name, int amount, float price);
    void deleteProduct();
    void display();
    std::string getProduct(int i);
    int getQuantity(int i);
    float getPrice(int i);
    int getNumberOfProducts() { return products.size(); };
    void clearBucket();
};
```

Comment: In what way is a bucket a kind of shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bucket.h` includes `Shop.h` which includes `Client.h` which includes `Bucket.h`... And so on forever and ever. This is a circular dependency.

`Shop.h` doesn't need to include `Client.h`, it only needs to *forward declare* the `Client` class:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "functions.h"
// #include "Client.h"

class Client;  // Forward declaration of the class, that's needed for pointers to it

class Shop {
    ...
};
```

The implementation of `Shop` needs the full definition of `Client`, so the `Shop` source file (`Shop.cpp`?) needs to include `Client.h`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the immediate issue, you'll need to forward declare `Client` class in `Shop.h`. However the class hierarchy you are building here is confusing to say the least, e.g. each `Client` owns a `Shop`, changing the class hierarchy to something more sensible should remove the problem altogether.